# What's the difference between .at_css to .css in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, search, nokogiri

I can't find a clear, direct answer, but what's the difference between `.at_css` and `.css` in Nokogiri?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Nokogiri has synonyms for the search-and-find-everything, and the find-the-first-one methods.

[`search`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#search-instance_method), [`/`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#search-instance_method), [`xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#xpath-instance_method) and [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#css-instance_method) all search for every occurrence of the accessor and return a [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet).

[`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#at-instance_method), [`%`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#at-instance_method), [`at_xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#at_xpath-instance_method) and [`at_css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#at_css-instance_method) search for the first occurrence and return a [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node). That is why the docs say they're equivalent to saying `search('//some/path').first` or `css('some path').first`.

Comment: Thanks, It makes alot more sense now :)